# char array initialized at the time of declaration?

Tags: c++, arrays, char, initialization

The MWE is

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    char array[255];
    cout << array[0] << "\n";
    cout << array[1] << "\n";
    cout << array[2] << "\n";
    cout << array[200] << "\n";
    cout << array[253] << "\n";
    cout << array[255] << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

And output is

```
\330
^M
`
\215
^@
^@
```

Although I don't know why the output creates this. But can I say 
"The array is initialized at the time of declaration."?

Comment: No. There is no initialisation here. (And as a result your program has undefined behaviour. Or possibly unspecified.)

Comment: Perhaps you meant `char array[256] = {0};`

Comment: @Ultimater, No, just char array[255];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your array is uninitialized, so it just has undefined values. You could initialize your array first:

```
char array[255] = {};
```

but this just populates it with the 0's. Also, note that you can't access index 255 here:

```
cout << array[255] << "\n";
```

this will try to access the 256th element of the array and you only have 255.

Comment: You could initialize the array that way, but then a bunch of `\0'` characters will be sent to `cout` since the array is not being filled with anything else.

Comment: Yes, but at least the behaviour is well-defined.

Answer (score 0):

There's no implicit initialization within c++.
In your case, the compiler allocates simply 255 bytes on the stack. The actual contents is arbitrary.

Comment: There is implicit initialization, just not in this particular case. For example, if this array was defined at namespace scope, it would be zeroed out.